# How to detect dependencies for Office dlls and SAP connector dlls with Installer project in .NET

Tags: c#, installation

I have a setup project whose primary output is from a Winforms based application.
My winforms application uses -

1. Microsoft.office.interop.excel.dll and Microsoft.VBe.Interop.dll
   Que - If the target machine does not have MS Office installed , my installer fails. what should be done for it, I have read on The office Primary Interop Assemblies (PIA)   is part of re-distributable package. but dont know if this is solution and how to use it in installer.
2. My App also uses SAP connector dlls, which are part of my application. But it need some more dlls to be part of System32 folder. Is there a way we can install theses dlls in system32 through Setup and how?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did -
1. Add launch condition with registry condition to check "Excel.Application", curVersion key exists on the target machine. If not, WE show the message.
2. For SAP dlls, add dlls to System folder in the setup.